# Difference between Mule enricher and setting invocation variable

Tags: mule

Is there any difference between setting a variable within Mule flow using `<set-variable>` versus setting a variable using enricher like `<enricher target="#[variable:xyz]"\>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `enricher` is designed for performing interactions like calling an outbound endpoint and bringing the result back to the main flow.

Using it as a replacement for `set-variable` would be semantically wrong, even if it works.

Comment: Thanks David. Can an enricher set property/variable in scope other than invocation. I need to carry result of enricher across flows.

Comment: It should be able to, yes.

Comment: Can you please enlighten now: This doesn't work `<enricher target="#[property:xyz]">`

Comment: This is not proper MEL syntax: try `#[message.outboundProperties.xyz]`

Comment: Thanks..It worked :). I was under impression that `#[message.outboundProperties.xyz]` is for getting xyz property not setting.

Answer (score 0):

What David Dossot described is absolutely correct. To add further to his description:

`The Message Enricher allows the current message to be augmented using data from a seperate resource. The Mule implementation of the Enrichment Resource (a source of data to augment the current message) can be any Message Processor`.

You can find Java API documentation for this at [MessageEnricher](http://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/current/apidocs/org/mule/enricher/MessageEnricher.html).

And of course, reading the Java doc really helps us a lot.

Answer (score 0):

there was significant difference between the message en-richer and set property.

message-enricher:
    it will enrich the mule message by calling external system or do some transformation to existing payload and save it into some scope of variable like session or outbound or invocation.Even if the transformation happens inside the message en-richer scope ,its doesn't effect the actual payload for the next component in flow.

set-property:

set property save some information extracted from payload or original payload to some invocation or flow scope variable.